# how to get consecutive value of a changing object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am New to Programming, and want to write a simple code that will allow me to get consecutive value from a live feed strings from server, where I need help is how to do below task

**First, let me make an example**

Like getting a live price update of Dash coin - let's says price is currently

- #1- $55, then it changes to
- #2- $56, then it changes to
- #3- $57, then it changes to
- #4- $58, then it changes to
- #5- $54, now it's no longer consecutive

The above shows a #4 consecutive increase in Price value
My question is How to set this function

#how to get changing values when it increases or decreases conservatively a number of times!

For instance, if I want to get an alert when the Dash Price increases consecutively #4 times or more in a row or any x number of times

Will appreciate a guide on how to go about this in JavaScript.

```
//ok first I tried the above BELOW, but I didn't get the expected results - how I used it below: What did I do wrong?

const WebSocket = require('ws');

var ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089');

var lastTick = null;

ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ticks:'R_100'}));
};

ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
   var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
   var currentTickTime = data.tick.epoch;
   var currentTick = data.tick.quote;
   const timerz = 1000;
   //console.log(currentTick,'\n', balance)
   var tickTime = new Date(currentTickTime * timerz).toLocaleString();
  

   //testing code below
   
   function handleNotification(){
    if (balance > 3){
        console.log("RISE UP-3times.");
        // Send notification that price is rising.
    }

    if (balance < -3){
        console.log("FALL DOWN-3times.");
        // Send notification that price is falling.
    }

   }
   
   var currentPrice = 0;
   var balance = 0;

   setInterval(async () => {
    const previousPrice = currentPrice;
    currentPrice =  await currentTick;
    if (currentPrice > previousPrice){
        //console.log('Higher Price')
        if (balance >= 0) balance++
        else balance = 0; 
    }else if (currentPrice < previousPrice){
        //console.log('Lower Price')
        if (balance <= 0) balance--
        else balance = 0;
    }else{
        // Price remains unchanged.
    } 

    handleNotification();
    console.log(currentPrice,'\n', balance)
}, 2000); 

  
    lastTick = currentTick;

};
```

I also tried the second option below but, the highest - num_consec value was 1 & -1, even when there are multiple consecutive higher than that.
Below is the code used:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

var ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var lastTick = null;
var lastTickTime = null;

ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ticks:'R_100'}));
};

ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
   var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
   var currentTickTime = data.tick.epoch;
   var currentTick = data.tick.quote;
   const timerz = 1000;
   //console.log(currentTick,'\n', balance)
   var tickTime = new Date(currentTickTime * timerz).toLocaleString();
   //console.log('ticks update: %o', currentTick, '\n', '-----------------------',tickTime);

   //testing code below
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   var price = lastTick; // or whatever initial value
   var num_consec = 0;
   var positive = true; //needs default

   setInterval(function() {
    var newprice = currentTick; // code to grab price from source, edit this to grab from your api
  
    if (Math.abs(price - newprice) >= 1) { // detect within a certain range, OP specified 1
      if (price - newprice > 0 && positive) { // consecutive up
        num_consec += 1;
      } else if (price - newprice < 0 && !(positive)) { // consecutive down
        num_consec += 1;
      } else if (price - newprice < 0 && positive) { // went down and broke streak
        num_consec = 0;
        positive = false;
      } else if (price - newprice > 0 && !(positive)) { //went up and broke streak
        num_consec = 0;
        positive = true;
      };
      price = newprice; //reset price delta
  
      console.log("Updated Info:",'\n', price, num_consec)// update price in html or elsewhere, console.log unnecessary
  
      if (num_consec > 2) {
        // do something with consec info
        console.log((positive) ? `Consecutive ${num_consec} times `+"up" : `Consecutive ${num_consec} times `+"down")
      };
    };
    newprice = null; // reset variable
  }, 1000); // check new price every 1000 ms (1s)

    //console.log(currentTick,'\n', num_consec)


    lastTick = currentTick;

    lastTickTime = tickTime;
};
```

will appreciate all the help I can get- Please kindly help me check the code to know what i did wrong

Comment: So you got the values in an array, like `[55, 56, 57, 58, 54]`?

Comment: Got value in JSON format, like below
{
      "close": 198.0644,
      "epoch": 1653945600,
      "high": 198.101,
      "low": 198.0028,
      "open": 198.0154
    }

, got the Price value, and the final object - as the price  but how to get when it increases consecutively. Just like I mentioned above

Comment: It's kind of a mess. First you can't define the function handleNotification inside the socket onmessage event. It needs to be defined outside. Second, it makes no sense to define an interval inside the onmessage event. The event only fires when you receive a new update. You should just take my second example out of the interval and drop it in where you in at the end of the onmessage event instead. Make sure to remove the await keyword. Also currentPrice and balance need to be defined outside of the socket event.
Honestly, you should probably just hire a freelancer to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy answer here.

```js
function handleNotification(){
    if (balance > 3){
        // Send notification that price is rising.
    }

    if (balance < -3){
        // Send notification that price is falling.
    }
}

var currentPrice = 0;
var balance = 0;

setInterval(async () => {
    const previousPrice = currentPrice;
    currentPrice = await getDashPrice();
    if (currentPrice > previousPrice){
        if (balance >= 0) balance++
        else balance = 0;
    }else if (currentPrice < previousPrice){
        if (balance <= 0) balance--
        else balance = 0;
    }else{
        // Price remains unchanged.
    }

    handleNotification();
}, 60000);
```

Nothing complicated. We just track the price. If the price is lower than when we last checked, we decrease the balance value. If it's higher, we increase it. If the balance value is positive and the price decreases, we set it back to 0 because it's no longer consecutive. And then vice versa.

Balance simply tracks how many negative or positive consecutive results occurred. This doesn't do much for you if the price change is very small though. You would need to add a threshold to the if statement if you'd like to make it less finely controlled.

Edit: Here's how you would do a threshold.

```js
var currentPrice = 0;
var balance = 0;
const threshold = 0.01; // 1%

setInterval(async () => {
    const previousPrice = currentPrice;
    const currentPriceTemp = await getDashPrice();
    if (currentPriceTemp > (previousPrice * (1 + threshold))){
        if (balance >= 0) balance++
        else balance = 0;
        currentPrice = currentPriceTemp;
    }else if (currentPriceTemp < (previousPrice * (1 - threshold))){
        if (balance <= 0) balance--
        else balance = 0;
        currentPrice = currentPriceTemp;
    }else{
        // Price remains unchanged.
    }

    handleNotification();
}, 60000);
```

That will multiply the previous price by 1.01 or 0.99 depending on if we're testing higher or lower. Basically the price change needs to be more than 1% higher or lower than the previous value. In this example, I also don't set currentPrice if the change didn't meet the 1% criteria. This avoids creeping if the change is less than 1% (e.g. it rises 0.5% 100 times in a row, the consecutive function would never trigger).

You can modify threshold variable to whatever you want and the code will only consider it consecutive if the value rises or falls by that percentage. `const threshold = 0.01;` is 1% and `const threshold = 0.99;` is 99%.

Comment: Wow am amazed and excited and eager to learn more now! Am very encouraged to try this out and thank you very much for a well detailed guide will try it all out one step after another and let you know how it goes

Comment: ok first I tried the above code, but I didn't get the expected results - how I used it below

Comment: PLEASE, how do I add the actual code where I used it so you can see what I did?

Comment: @TMNmedia you need to add it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I have added it so u can help review it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this the following way to avoid blocking your thread, but periodically keep checking for a specific range of change. Unfortunately measuring consecutive change is not super simple but can be done with the code below.

Possible implementation of `setInterval():`

```js
var price = 50; // or whatever initial value
var num_consec = 0;
var positive = true; //needs default
setInterval(function() {
  var newprice = ...; // code to grab price from source, edit this to grab from your api

  if (Math.abs(price - newprice) >= 1) { // detect within a certain range, OP specified 1
    if (price - newprice > 0 && positive) { // consecutive up
      num_consec += 1;
    } else if (price - newprice < 0 && !(positive)) { // consecutive down
      num_consec += 1;
    } else if (price - newprice < 0 && positive) { // went down and broke streak
      num_consec = 0;
      positive = false;
    } else if (price - newprice > 0 && !(positive)) { //went up and broke streak
      num_consec = 0;
      positive = true;
    };
    price = newprice; //reset price delta

    console.log("Updated Info:", price, num_consec)// update price in html or elsewhere, console.log unnecessary

    if (num_consec > 2) {
      // do something with consec info
      console.log((positive) ? `Consecutive ${num_consec} times `+"up" : `Consecutive ${num_consec} times `+"down")
    };
  };
  newprice = null; // reset variable
}, 1000); // check new price every 1000 ms (1s)
```

**Test Cases (Ouput):**

Increasing:

```
Test price Value:47
file.html:24 Updated Info: 47 0
file.html:40 Test price Value:46
file.html:24 Updated Info: 46 0
file.html:40 Test price Value:45
file.html:24 Updated Info: 45 1
file.html:40 Test price Value:44
file.html:24 Updated Info: 44 2
file.html:40 Test price Value:43
file.html:24 Updated Info: 43 3
file.html:28 Consecutive 3 times up
file.html:40 Test price Value:44
file.html:24 Updated Info: 44 0
file.html:40 Test price Value:43
file.html:24 Updated Info: 43 0
```

Decreasing:

```
file.html:40 Test price Value:64
file.html:24 Updated Info: 64 0
file.html:40 Test price Value:65
file.html:24 Updated Info: 65 0
file.html:40 Test price Value:66
file.html:24 Updated Info: 66 1
file.html:40 Test price Value:67
file.html:24 Updated Info: 67 2
file.html:40 Test price Value:68
file.html:24 Updated Info: 68 3
file.html:28 Consecutive 3 times down
file.html:40 Test price Value:69
file.html:24 Updated Info: 69 4
file.html:28 Consecutive 4 times down
file.html:40 Test price Value:70
file.html:24 Updated Info: 70 5
file.html:28 Consecutive 5 times down
file.html:40 Test price Value:71
file.html:24 Updated Info: 71 6
file.html:28 Consecutive 6 times down
file.html:40 Test price Value:70
file.html:24 Updated Info: 70 0
file.html:40 Test price Value:69
file.html:24 Updated Info: 69 1
```

If this did not answer your question, or you’d like additional help, please direct message me so we can work through your issue.

Comment: Wow am amazed and excited and eager to learn more now! Am very encouraged to try this out and thank you very much for a well detailed guide will try it all out one step after another and let you know how it goes

Comment: Please kindly help me check the code - I updated it in the question session - the result  never gives higher than -1 or 1 at every point

Comment: how do I direct message you